# Unable to understand firstTerm = secondTerm; secondTerm = nextTerm; in fibonacci series

Tags: fibonacci

```java
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n = 5, firstTerm = 0, secondTerm = 1;
    System.out.println("Fibonacci Series till " + n + " terms:");
    

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
      System.out.print(firstTerm + " ");

      // compute the next term
      int nextTerm = firstTerm + secondTerm;
         firstTerm = secondTerm;
         secondTerm = nextTerm;
    
    }
  }
}
```

//Q) Unable to understand why firstTerm = secondTerm;
secondTerm = nextTerm; statement is written, can anyone explain me this concept

Comment: Because that's what the fibonacci series _is_. You're going to add firstTerm and secondTerm together each time thru the loop, so before the next iteration of the loop, you need to update them both so they are the _correct_ terms for the next iteration, namely, last two terms of the _current_ series. Perhaps you would have been happier if these had been called `penultimateTerm` and `lastTerm`.

Answer (score 0):

The fibonnaci sequence is defined by

```
F(0) = 0 // This is our first term
F(1) = 1 // This is the second term
F(n) = F(n - 1) + F(n - 2)
```

To calculate a term that is neither the first term, nor the second term, we need to sum, the two previous terms.
This is the reason why while iterating, the second term value is assigned to the first term and so on

You will have more details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)

Comment: Thanks a lot! however what is the meaning of this statement firstTerm = secondTerm;
         secondTerm = nextTerm

Comment: I'm a beginner....

Comment: They are assigning the value of the secondTerm to firstTerm and the value of nextTerm to secondTerm.
If we have firstTerm = 5, secondTerm = 8 and nextTerm = 13, at the end, we will have : firstTerm = 8 and secondTerm = 13

Comment: @DeepakSuri There's no point discussing this if you don't even know what `=` means.

Comment: I know this @matt, thanks a lot for the prompt reply I am a mathematics graduates but not good in understanding programming logic